# http://localhost:3000/microposts/new can't open

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading 'Ruby on rails toturial' by Michael Hart.

I followed all the steps and did this command:

> $ rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user id:integer

But still can't open: http://localhost:3000/microposts/new

How can I make this micropost page open?

Thank you.
Jonas

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: you type `"user id"` instead of `"user_id"` is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the _ in your command. It should be

```
 rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:integer
```

Destroy the scaffold using the following command.

```
 rails destroy scaffold Micropost
```

Create the scaffold again.

```
 rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:integer
```

If you visit the page, I think you might get migration pending error. So run the following command to resolve the issue.

```
rake db:migrate
```

This command will add microposts table to your database. Now you will be good

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found this answer:

Run command:

```
rails server
```

Comment: Next time you should really do some research before asking, this was an extremely simple solution that could have been solved within 30 seconds of researching

Comment: if only that was true. I did research.